# How to retrieve website source without using ioutil.ReadAll in golang

Tags: http, go, get

My code:

```
func getSourceUrl(url string) (string, error) {
   resp, err := http.Get(url)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error getSourceUrl: ")
       return "", err
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()
   body := resp.Body
   // time = 0
   sourcePage, err := ioutil.ReadAll(body)
   // time > 5 minutes
   return string(sourcePage), err
}
```

I have a website link with a source of around> 100000 lines. Using ioutil.ReadAll made me get very long (about> 5 minutes for 1 link). Is there a way to get Source website faster? Thank you!

Comment: Before you start optimising - you need to understand **WHY** and **WHAT** is slow. It's plenty of various performance analysis tools for go. Make a research, then come back with some results.

Comment: I checked, after each line of code I checked the time, and I saw in the line "sourcePage, err: = ioutil.ReadAll (body)" that it stood still for 5 minutes. There is no other process. So I just concluded that reading the web source> 100k line made it slow. And of course not by the network. Because my network is using 50Mb / s.

Comment: 100k lines means nothing. How large is the response? What's the network interface saturation/utilisation during this procedure? If you request the same resource with `curl` is it any faster?

Comment: You can test with this link: https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00279.md5

Comment: http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4557/24460286198_d06c6fa910_o.png
I tried it in less than a minute. :(
But it is still a long time to get 300 links. It takes about 7.5 hours for 300 links

Comment: You did not answer any of the 3 questions I asked above.

Comment: @Minato please run this `time wget https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00279.md5` and let us know what you see. Even if your network 'locally' fast, you can have all sort of delays on the way to you starting from the source website.

Comment: @Minato this is not your code or local network it is the source website and the distance (origin appears to be in US you appear to be in Vietnam). I'm on 150Mbit/s in Netherlands (so halfway) and it still takes 20sec. wget ~145KB/s. The file is 2Mb. Try go concurrent magic, perhaps this is simply per transfer throttling at the source in which case you can get your files much faster in parallel. Good luck.

Comment: @biosckon I checked, it gave the result:.... 2.06M 49.0KB/s in 87s; real 1m29...
And I tried to use goroutine, get 300 link only take nearly 1 hour only.

Comment: @zerkms I'm sorry, I'm really bad. :( I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

@Minato try this code, play with `M` throttling parameter. Play with it if you get too errors (reduce it).

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

// Token is an empty struct for signalling
type Token struct{}

// N files to get
var N = 301 // at the source 00000 - 00300

// M max go routines
var M = runtime.NumCPU() * 16

// Throttle to max M go routines
var Throttle = make(chan Token, M)

// DoneStatus is used to signal end of
type DoneStatus struct {
    length   int
    sequence string
    duration float64
    err      error
}

// ExitOK is simple exit counter
var ExitOK = make(chan DoneStatus)

// TotalBytes read
var TotalBytes = 0

// TotalErrors captured
var TotalErrors = 0

// URLTempl is templte for URL construction
var URLTempl = "https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_%05d.md5"

func close(c io.Closer) {
    err := c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    log.Printf("start main. M=%d\n", M)
    startTime := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {

        go func(idx int) {
            // slow ramp up fire getData after i seconds
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Second)

            url := fmt.Sprintf(URLTempl, idx)
            _, _ = getData(url) // errors captured as data
        }(i)
    }

    // Count N byte count signals
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        status := <-ExitOK
        TotalBytes += status.length

        if status.err != nil {
            TotalErrors++
            log.Printf("[%d] : %v\n", i, status.err)
            continue
        }

        log.Printf("[%d] file %s, %.1f MByte, %.1f min, %.1f KByte/sec\n",
            i, status.sequence,
            float64(status.length)/(1024*1024),
            status.duration/60,
            float64(status.length)/(1024)/status.duration)
    }

    // totals
    duration := time.Since(startTime).Seconds()
    log.Printf("Totals: %.1f MByte, %.1f min, %.1f KByte/sec\n",
        float64(TotalBytes)/(1024*1024),
        duration/60,
        float64(TotalBytes)/(1024)/duration)

    // using fatal to verify only one go routine is running at the end
    log.Fatalf("TotalErrors: %d\n", TotalErrors)
}

func getData(url string) (data []byte, err error) {

    var startTime time.Time

    defer func() {
        // release token
        <-Throttle

        // signal end of go routine, with some status info
        ExitOK <- DoneStatus{
            len(data),
            url[41:46],
            time.Since(startTime).Seconds(),
            err,
        }
    }()

    // acquire one of M tokens
    Throttle <- Token{}

    log.Printf("Started file: %s\n", url[41:46])

    startTime = time.Now()

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer close(resp.Body)

    data, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

Per transfer variation is about 10-40KByte/sec and final total for all 301 files I get 928MB, 11.1min at 1425 KByte/sec.  I believe you should be able to get similar results.

`// outside the scope of the question but maybe useful`

Also give this a try http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/ go to settings and select bunch of US servers for testing and set duration to 60sec. This will tell you what your actual effective total rate is to US.

Good luck!

Comment: My only is 3-5Kb / s. May be due to fiber optic cable is broken so that international connections are slow.
Thank u~~~

Comment: Download 54,4 megabit/s, up 60,4 megabit/s. Overall : D, Quality: D, Speed: -, BufferBloat: -

Comment: @MInato play with trying to run this code at different times of day. You may see interesting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate sections of the response at a time, something like;

```
responseSection := make([]byte, 128)
body.Read(responseSection)
return string(responseSection), err
```

Which would read 128 bytes at a time. However would suggest confirming the download speed is not causing the slow load.

Comment: What is so special in the 128 bytes size? Why not 4096 or 65535?

Comment: 128 is arbitrary, could be anything.

Comment: "could be anything" --- it's exactly how you **NOT** make performance optimisations.

Comment: Yes. But without knowing the constraints defining the number is impossible.

Comment: Correct. That's the exact reason why performance optimisation should be preceded with analysis, not with writing code with random constants, praying that in this particular case it would magically work.

Comment: And now we have come to the conclusion that your answer actually not likely to help haven't we? ;-)

Comment: It would be quicker, but as I said in answer likely not where the bottleneck is.

Comment: "It would be quicker" --- uhm, that's a speculation. There really is no reason for it to be quicker for the few megabytes. Given the OP has problem for that code to run for 5+ minutes, your answer provides 0 help in solving the real problem, sorry.

Comment: I tried, instead of 128, I changed 65000 and 10000000. But the result it is the same. That is, it only gets to a certain line no matter how big the number is. For example. 128 => to the fourth line; 65000 => to the 500th line; but it's also up to the 500th line. You can test with the link: "https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00279.md5"

Comment: Why not just do 
`io.copy(ioutil.discard resp.body)`

Answer (score 0):

The 5 minutes is probably network time.
That said, you generally would not want to buffer enormous objects in memory.
resp.Body is a Reader.
So you cold use io.Copy to copy its contents into a file.
Converting sourcePage into a string is a bad idea as it forces another allocation.

Comment: "enormous objects in memory" --- what does "enormous" mean?

Comment: It's definitely not due to networking. Because my network is using 50Mb / s

Comment: @Minato you are confusing your ISP plan speed and actual speed in this very case. So far you have not provided any meaningful numbers, just your assumptions and guesses.

Comment: "enormous" means very big